# toggle div pushing down other divs

Tags: css, html, containers

I have 3 divs on a form page of my website. The top left toggle overlaps the bottom div whenever i click the toggle button.

What I'm trying to do is that the bottom left div container should move down when the top div container is clicked and move back to it's former position when toggle is closed.

I have included the css for the right div, I dont know if that is the css afecting the positions of the two div 's beside it.

**Before Toggle**

[image]

**After Toggle**

[image]

**CSS for Toggle**

```
#toggle-view {
list-style:none;    
font-family:arial;
font-size:10px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:200px; 
position: absolute;
}

#toggle-view li {
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:'lato';
    padding:2px;
    margin:10px;
    margin-left:20px;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer; 
    border-radius: 5px;    
}

 #toggle-view li a:hover {
    color: brown;  
}

#toggle-view h3 {
    margin:0;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#2a5a9a;
}

#toggle-view span {
    position:absolute;
    right:5px; top:0;
    color:#2a5a9a;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

#toggle-view p {
    margin:5px 0;
    display:none;
}

#toggle-view a{
    padding:5px 0;
    color:#35371c; 
}

#toggle-view a:hover{

     color:#2a5a9a;
}
```

**CSS for LeftBox**

```
.report{
position: absolute;
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:0;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

**CSS for Right Box**

```
.register-body {
height:auto;
font-size:1em;
width:710px;
position:relative;
color:#000;
border-radius:5px;
background-color:#d2d4bb;
line-height:20px;         
margin:20px 0 20px 250px;
padding:15px 15px 0; 
}
```

When I changed

```
#toggle-view {
position: absolute;
}
```

to

```
#toggle-view {
position: relative;
}
```

and

```
.report{
 position: absolute;
}
```

to

```
.report{
 position: relative;
 }
```

I got this :

[image]

The Right Box is pushed below the bottom left box.

**UPDATE**

My **HTML**

For Toggle:

```
<ul id="toggle-view">
<li>
    <h3>Create View Comment</h3>
        <span>+</span>
            <p>
                <a href="forum.php">Forum Homepage </a><br>
                <a href="create-topic.php">Create Topic </a><br>
                <a href="view-topic.php">View Topics</a><br>
                <a href="forum-stat.php">Forum Stats</a><br>
            </p>
</li>
```

For Left Bottom Form

```
<div class='headword'>Report A User</div>
     p>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
          <?php
           $user = mysql_query("SELECT forum_id, username, first_name, last_name, email
             FROM forum_login ORDER BY username ASC") or die(mysql_error());

  echo"User <select name='username' class='tap_Select' title='User You Want To Report'>
                    <option value =''>    </option>";
                    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($user)){                                            
       echo '<option value="'.$row1['username'].'">'.$row1['username'].'</option>';} 
                       echo '</select>' ; ?><br>
   <select name="type" class="tap_Select" title='What Are You Reporting For'>
        <option value ="">    </option>
        <option value ="bullying">Bullying</option>
        <option value ="trolling">Trolling</option>
        <option value ="spamming">Spamming</option>
        </select> 
         <br>
        <textarea type="text" name="desc"  style="width:150px ; height: 100px;">

       </textarea><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit1" class="tap1_Btn">
       </form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle div container overlapping another container under it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415193/toggle-div-container-overlapping-another-container-under-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without your full html, I would say it's your `position: absolute` in your `.report` css.  Absolute will pull it out of the normal layout flow so that any other `div` will just collide with it unless you either change the `top` value one toggle or you put it back into the flow with a `position: relative` or `position: static`.

I would just remove the `position: absolute` and adjust your `padding` and `margin` so that it flows where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

**Update after seeing the live page:**

Add a div around `<ul id="toggle-view"></ul><div class="report"></div>` like this and let the `<div class="register-body"></div>` be after it outside:

```
<div class="left_pane">
    <ul id="toggle-view">
        ...
    </ul>
    <div class="report">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="register-body">
...
</div>
```

Add `.left_pane` to css and set the flowing:

```
.left_pane {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Drop the `position: absolute;` at your `#toggle-view`.

For `.register-body` add the `float: left;` and change `margin:    20px 0 20px 250px;` to `margin:    20px 0 20px 20px;`

And it should be all ok ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I did this, the form would move down whenever I clicked the toggle, and move back up when toggle is closed

Comment: Could you upload your final output on a webpage so I can see it completely? There may be other CSS or tags in your page that affect them, with the info you provided as CSS and HTML, I tested in a HTML file and with removing of position: absolute; from #toggle-view problem solved for me ...

Comment: [Sample Page](http://tinyurl.com/8k2gqsl)  Here is a sample page of a sa[le page that gives this error.

Comment: looking at your page, it's completely messy, there are lots of design problem in it, I suggest to consider a re design if it's possible. But anyway I will edit this answer to a final one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please be specific on what you meant be messy? Of Course I can do a redesign. Is it the layout generally or code syntax ? Or logic ? I most appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You have used lots of absolute positionings while it's not cool to have a absolute layout. Your layout probably is designed for a widescreen and is not flexible in 1024x768 ... You may need to read some articles about designing a proper layout for website if you are going to redesign or fix this one.

Comment: Can you please point me to some good articles ? I'll be so glad. Thank you.

Comment: A good page to know about different methods in designing layouts: 
http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/a-guide-on-layout-types-in-web-design/ 

A basic starting guide: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp 

This page has lot's of good examples at bottom, you can explore their CSS/HTML codes: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/layout/

Comment: Thank you for the links.I most appreciate them.